# Does Qt provide a timer to calculate elapsed CPU time?

Tags: qt, timer

I checked QTimer and QBasicTimer. But they are not for the purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [QElapsedTimer](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qelapsedtimer.html) is exactly (or closest of) what you need.

Answer (score 1):

No, the timers provided by Qt are for automation/animation purposes, or general timing to (roughly) millisecond accuracy.

If you need cross-platform, as accurate as possible timing, I recommend using [Boost::Timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/timer/doc/cpu_timers.html).